# How can I disable the Wi-Fi connection of my Android phone from my laptop?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean

Is it somehow possible to control the Wi-Fi connection of my Android phone from my laptop to disable (not only disconnect) the Wi-Fi connection of my phone if both my phone and my laptop are connected to the same network?

USB-Debugging is enabled on this device.

Comment: Do you want to disable or disconnect from the Wi-Fi? Is USB debugging enabled or SSH server running on device?

Comment: Dear @Firelord, USB-Debugging is enabled but no SSH server running. I want to completely disable Wi-Fi and not only disconnect to conserve energy.

Comment: If you have root access then through USB or Wi-Fi but using debugging mode, this command can work: `adb shell su -c 'svc wifi disable'`.

Comment: It returns `error: device '(null)' not found`. How can my laptop know my device over Wi-Fi, assuming that there could be other phones on the same network, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is non-root method:

1. Create a dummy app in Android Studio. [[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12420590/1074998)]

MainActivity.java, put right after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`:

```
WifiManager wfm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
try {
    wfm.setWifiEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(getIntent().getStringExtra("wifi")));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
System.exit(0);
```

AndroidManifest.xml, put before `<application`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

1. Enabled USB debugging settings, plug USB cable to your phone,  press Shift+F10 to run the app which will also install the app.
2. In your phone, navigate to **Advanced Wi-Fi** and get the IPv4 address.
3. While USB cable still plugged, issue `adb shell` command,
4. Issue `pm list packages` command to find out the package name if not sure. For example **package:com.blogspot.diannaoxiaobai.dummyonly**, remove the prefix **package:** is your package name. Or you can simply get the package name in AndroidManifest.xml, e.g. `package="com.blogspot.diannaoxiaobai.dummyonly"`.
5. Issue `setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555` ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219466/1074998)) command.
6. Ctrl+D to quit adb session.
7. Unplug your cable. Reboot your phone now.
8. Assume your phone automatically connected to wifi on reboot, and your laptop connected to the same wifi network. No need any USB cable now.
9. Issue `adb connect 192.168.11.5`, in which this ip get from step #2 above.
10. Issue `adb shell am start -n com.blogspot.diannaoxiaobai.dummyonly/.MainActivity -e wifi false` to disable wifi. **com.blogspot.diannaoxiaobai.dummyonly** is the package name get from step #4 above.
11. You can remove the port 5555 set from step #5 above with `adb shell setprop persist.adb.tcp.port ""` command. ([Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32546502/1074998))